# passing rather huge arguments to ruby script, problems?

Tags: ruby

```
ruby somescript.rb somehugelonglistoftextforprocessing
```

is this a bad idea? rather should i create a separate flat file containig the somehugelonglistoftextforprocessing, and let somescript.rb read it ?

does it matter if the script argument is very very long text(1KB~300KB) ? what are some problems that can arise if any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as the limits of your command-line handling code (e.g., `bash` or `ruby` itself) are not exceeded, you should have no *technical* problems in doing this.

Whether it's a *good* idea is another matter. Do you really want to have to type in a couple of hundred kilobytes *every* single time you run your program? Do you want to have to remember to put quotes around your data if it contains spaces?

There are a number of ways I've seen this handled which you may want to consider (this list is by no means exhaustive):

- Change your code so that, if there's no arguments, read the information from standard input - this will allow you to do either
     `ruby somescript.rb myData`
  or
     `ruby somescript.rb <myFile.txt`.
- Use a special character to indicate file input (I've seen `@` used in this way). So,
     `ruby somescript.rb myData`
  would use the data supplied on the command line whilst
     `ruby somescript.rb @myFile.txt`
  would get the data from the file.

My advice would be to use the file-based method for that size of data and allow an argument to be used if specified. This covers both possible scenarios:

- Lots of data, put it in a file so you won't have to retype it every time you want to run your command.
- Not much data, allow it to be passed as an argument so that you don't have to create a file for something that's easier to type in on the command line.

Comment: I second paxdiablo's recommendation. There's some good discussion of this approach on [another SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273262/best-practices-with-stdin-in-ruby) that might be useful