# Piping stdin to ruby script via `myapp | myscript.rb`

Tags: ruby, stdin

I have an app that runs continuously, dumping output from a server and sending strings to stdout. I want to process this output with a Ruby script. The strings are `\n`-terminated.

For example, I'm trying to run this on the command line:

`myapp.exe | my_script.rb`

...with `my_script.rb` defined as:

```
while $stdin.gets
    puts $_
end
```

I ultimately am going to process the strings using regexes and display some summary data, but for now I'm just trying to get the basic functionality hooked up. When I run the above, I get the following error:

```
my_script.rb:1:in `gets': Bad file descriptor (Errno::EBADF)
        from my_script.rb:1
```

I am running this on Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2 and Ruby 1.8.6.

How do I continuously process stdin in a Ruby script?  (Continuously as in not processing a file, but running until I kill it.)

**EDIT:**

I was able to make this work, sort of.  There were several problems standing in my way.  For one thing, it may be that using Ruby to process the piped-in `stdin` from another process [doesn't work on Windows 2003R2](http://soeck.blogspot.com/2004/06/bad-file-descriptor-for.html).  Another direction, suggested by Adrian below, was to run my script as the parent process and use `popen` to connect to `myapp.exe` as a `fork`ed child process.  Unfortunately, `fork` isn't implemented in Windows, so this didn't work either.

Finally I was able to download [POpen4](http://popen4.rubyforge.org/), a RubyGem that does implement `popen` on Windows.  Using this in combination with Adrian's suggestion, I was able to write this script which does what I really want -- processes the output from `myapp.exe`:

### file: my_script.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'popen4'

 status =
    POpen4::popen4("myapp.exe") do |stdout, stderr, stdin, pid|
        puts pid
        while s = stdout.gets
            puts s
        end

    end
```

This script echoes the output from `myapp.exe`, which is exactly what I want.

Comment: Have you tried running the ruby script without the pipe and typing things in to test it? Your code works on my computer.

Comment: @Adrian:  Yes, my script runs fine by itself.  It echoes everything I type in, as expected and desired.

Comment: Try just plain `gets`, without the `$stdin`. If that doesn't work, you might have to examine the output of `myapp.exe` for non-printable characters with another ruby script, using `IO.popen`.

Comment: @Adrian: Unfortunately `fork` doesn't work on Windows, and `popen` uses `fork`.  Is there some secret incantation I can employ to get it to work?

Comment: The only thing I can think of would be to temporarily rewrite `myapp.exe` to exit after a certain number of lines and then use `%x`.

Comment: @Adrian:  I got it to work.  Your comment didn't quite get me there, but it set me on the path.  I'll edit my post with the solution I used.  If you change your comment about `popen` as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just plain `gets`, without the `$stdin`. If that doesn't work, you might have to examine the output of `myapp.exe` for non-printable characters with another ruby script, using `IO.popen`.

Answer (score 0):

`gets` doesn't always use stdin but instead tries to open a file.

See [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273262/best-practices-with-stdin-in-ruby).

Comment: When I replace `$stdin` with `ARGF` in my code I still get the same error.  Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0):

Try executing your Ruby script by explicitly calling ruby:

```
myapp.exe | ruby my_script.rb
```

I've experienced some odd behavior using stdin in Ruby when relying on Windows to invoke the correct program based on the file associations.