# How do I tell from within a ruby script whether it has been run from the command line or from a non-interactive process?

Tags: ruby

How do I tell from within a ruby script whether it has been run from the command line, i.e. like this:

```
> ruby myscript.rb
```

or from a non-interactive process, e.g. cron?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$stdin.tty?` will return true if connected to a terminal otherwise false.

There is a fair bit of additional information on question [Best practices with STDIN in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273262/best-practices-with-stdin-in-ruby)