# Detecting stdin content in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to know whether or not someone is trying to give a ruby program content on stdin. I do not want ruby to fall back to allowing interactive input. How do I do this?

```
# When called in bash like this, I want 'cat.rb' to exit immediately:
ruby cat.rb

# When called in bash like this, I want to see the word 'hello':
echo hello | ruby cat.rb
```

If I just have `cat.rb` contain `puts gets` then the first example will block, waiting for an EOF on interactive stdin. I don't want to modify the calling command, but wish to support both kinds of behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at `$stdin.tty?`

```
ruby cat.rb
# $stdin.tty? -> true

echo hello | ruby cat.rb
# $stdin.tty? -> false
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273262/best-practices-with-stdin-in-ruby This solution is listed there too.