# How to make a standard Unix Filter using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file-io, io

I found this ruby problem on RubyQuiz, which states besides the problem itself, the following:

> "The script should be a standard Unix filter, reading from files
>   specified on the command-line or STDIN and writing to STDOUT.  Each line of input will contain one integer (between 1 and 3999) expressed as an Arabic or Roman numeral"

I have no idea how to do a **Unix Filter** using Ruby.. *to read files* in this case,

Could somebody please enlighten me on how to accomplish this task in the best way possible.

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to read files from STDIN is using ARGF, as explained in this answer:
[Best practices with STDIN in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273262/best-practices-with-stdin-in-ruby/273841#273841)

You can write to STDOUT using puts or printf.

For more detailed info about IO in Ruby, read the Ruby Doc:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html

Comment: I think that's a pretty good link. Too bad I didn't find it previously.

Comment: Note that `puts` will append a line end, `printf` won't.

Comment: you also need to read about the pipe and filter pattern http://www.dossier-andreas.net/software_architecture/pipe_and_filter.html