# ruby how to pipe arguements to a bin

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby bin I'd like to pass information to in this fashion:

```
some_text | ./bin/my_ruby_bin
```

where some_text will be accessible by `ARGV`

is this possible with ruby + shell or am I taking the wrong approach here?

Comment: The data will come to STDIN so you will want to read from that.

Comment: ahh so maybe something like echo 'some_text' | bin

Comment: thanks for pointing me in right direction, this post looks promising http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273262/best-practices-with-stdin-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple solution that works for my cause, but it appears there are many ways to do this:

```
# ./bin/my_ruby_bin
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -n
puts "hello: #{$_}"
```

notice the `-n` flag

from command line:

```
echo 'world' | ./bin/my_ruby_bin
# => hello world
```

More on `ruby -n`

```
ruby -h
-n assume 'while gets(); ... end' loop around your script
```