# How can I get piped data with arguments on Ruby2.4

Tags: ruby, pipe, postfix-mta

In Python3, I have this code:

```
arg, unk = parser.parse_known_args()
buf = ''

for line in fileinput.input(unk):
    buf += line
fileinput.close()
```

This code allows me to get piped data along with arguments to the program.

What I am achieving is to get piped e-mail from **postfix**. Postfix *pipe email file to my python app* and also **add some arguments** that I want. In Ruby I cannot find a proper way of doing this. Piped data can be max. ~25MB. So I need a correct, proper and smooth way of handling this. I want to handle even large files without issues.

`ruby test.rb --option ARG`

Of course, I can get arguments easily but I also want to get **PIPED** data.

In fact, I cannot find exact method that Ruby has for getting piped data. I am stuck at this point. Can anyone give me a hand on this?

Comment: God sake, I searched many terms. ARGF? I just learned this now and yes, This is what I want. In fact more than what I want. I found many useful methods that I can implement for myself. Thanks. --Maybe add as an answer? **Also** thanks to you now, I found a simple sample. Maybe useful for others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273262/best-practices-with-stdin-in-ruby

Comment: Yep, great find!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in ruby you want to read from [ARGF](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/ARGF.html). It handles files passed as filenames or piped to your program.