# SQLite3 commands in ruby

Tags: ruby, sqlite, cmd

Is there a way to pass commands from `SQLite` into ruby script?
For example I have a `test.sqlite` database created. Now I want to export a query result from that database into `.csv` file. I can simply do that using command line:

```
Sqlite3 "H:\\test.sqlite"
.mode csv
.headers on
.once test.csv
select * from cars;

Sqlite3 "H:\\test.sqlite"
.mode csv
.headers on
.once test.csv
select * from cars;
```

or also using SQLite3:

```
sqlite3 -header -csv sqlite3 -header -csv H:\test.sqlite< query.sql > test.csv
```

and it works perfectly fine in CMD but I want to have that coded in my ruby script. I was also trying to pass that into command line using `%x` but it is not working.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You could receive the STDIN by using pipes, someone asked that here ([Best practices with STDIN in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273262/best-practices-with-stdin-in-ruby))

Or you could also use the sqlite gem(https://rubygems.org/gems/sqlite3/versions/1.3.11) to connect to the database and then run the query from ruby.

You can also use sequel(https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) the interface is nicer, to communicate with the sqlite database

Answer (score 0):

Simply system("sqlite3 -header -csv sqlite3 -header -csv H:\test.sqlite< query.sql > test.csv"

I just needed to add 2 slashes in path...

Answer (score 0):

The question is not exactly defined.

Firstly read the documentation for the [sqlite3 gem](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/luislavena/sqlite3-ruby/SQLite3/Database) and [csv library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html).

Using this information, you can parse and write csv-files, make queries and get results to/from SQLite3 DB and much more.