# Permission Denied when passing files to a ruby program

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, command-line

I have a ruby program that accepts files as input. I am trying to test that this functionality works by piping a file into the program by entering

`cat file1.txt | ./app.rb`

However, when I do this I get `-bash: ./app.rb: Permission denied`
I have tried using `sudo cat file1.txt | ./app.rb` which prompts me for my password and then it appears nothing happens.

This works fine when I instead type 
`ruby app.rb file1.txt`

Does anyone have any tips for how to get this to work?

As pointed out in the comments, I need to be able to read a file path from stdin AND pass them as parameters:

In my code I have this:

```
def input
    if ARGV.length.positive?
      ARGV
    else
      gets.chomp.split(' ')
    end
  end
```

I expect `input` to return an array of file paths.

Comment: Reading from a file and from [stdin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) are two different things.

Comment: This might help: [Best practices with STDIN in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/273262/3776858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, sending the contents of a file as STDIN to a program and passing the filename as a parameter are two very different things.

I cannot say which, if either, is "right" or "wrong" without knowing more context of what it is you're actually trying to achieve, but it's important to recognise the difference.

---

Now, the actual cause of the error here is that you're trying to **execute** the ruby file directly. You can fix this by running `ruby` on the filename instead:

```
cat file1.txt | ruby app.rb
```

It *is* possible to execute the file without writing `ruby`, but you must first make it executable:

```
chmod +x app.rb
```

And also write a [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the top of the file, to specify that it should be executed as a ruby script, not a bash script (which is the default):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

Comment: If you type `ls -l app.rb`, you should see something like this: `-rw-r--r--`. This is the unix [file permissions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm). See the link for more detail... But since there's no `x` in that list, you don't have permission to e**x**ecute the file. Running `chmod +x` adds execution permission.

Comment: I actually need to be able to do both, send the file path as stdin and as a parameter. I will elaborate more in my question.

Comment: OK.. I think what you're looking for is actually `echo file1.txt`, not `cat file1.txt`. You want to pass the file **name**, not the file **contents**.

Comment: Anyway, I think my answer is still correct. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you for the response. `cat file1.txt | ruby app.rb` worked like a charm. The Shebang didn't seem to help. I placed it at the top of `app.rb`. I am using MacOs if that helps.

Comment: I basically need the program to accept a list of one or more file paths (e.g. ./app.rb file1.txt file2.txt ...). and also accepts input on stdin (e.g. cat file1.txt | ./app.rb). @tomlord

Comment: @EmilyKingan My point is you "expect `input` to return an array of file paths", but by running `cat file1.txt`, you are not sending the file *path* via STDIN, you are sending the file *contents* via STDIN. That's why I suggest instead using `echo file1.txt`, to only send the file *path*.